# How commonly does "done" replace "did"?

Tags: word-usage, slang, dialects

How common is it for native English speakers to actively replace the past tense 'did' with the past participle 'done'?  I used to think it was only really done in rather vulgar dialects, but I have increasingly heard this usage now by people who speak otherwise normal Received Pronunciation, or Standard American English:

> I done the report.  You done it yesterday.  He done it already.

I can't help but interpret this replacement of 'did' as sounding somehow uneducated, but is it becoming a standard in some dialects?  Is the word 'did' dying out?  And do these speakers use the 'done' replacement when switching the word order around in a question; for example, would they say:

> Done you do it today?

... or even:

> Done you it today?

... instead of:

> Did you do it today?

Comment: _Done_ is not perfect tense, it's a Past Participle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using *done* for *did* is definitely a hallmark of uneducated dialects of English, notably but not limited to rural Southern and Western American. But I have never heard anyone use that as "Done you do it today?" or "Done you it today?"

Nevertheless, there *are* some rather twisted and arcane constructions on record using *done*. Take for example [the "crows" scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIDl8Wb1va0) from Disney's 1941 movie *Dumbo*, a rather racist (cf. [Jim Crow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws), a pejorative term for Negro) depiction of African-American dialect (which would have been an extension of the Southern American dialect). One of the lines in the song the crows sing (about 3:45 in the clip) is

> Well I be done seen about everything
>   When I see an elephant fly.

That said, this depiction is also meant to represent uneducated speech.

**Supplement:**

You will sometimes hear this doubled up with *did* for emphasis:

> I done did it.

Comment: +1: Nice answer, although I wouldn't count on the authenticity of Disney's version of AAVE.

Answer (score 3):

In UK English using "done" like this definitely sounds childish or uneducated; in my opinion your comment on "vulgar dialects" is about right.
I don't know if it's more prevalent in different regions, but I do hear it quite a lot in the north-east and it always sounds jarring.

I would strongly recommend sticking with

> I *did* the report. You *did* it yesterday. He *did* it already.

As to your other questions, even those who do use *done* in this way would NOT say:

> Done you do it today?

or

> Done you it today?

Answer (score 2):

The NOAD reports that *done* is informally used:

- as nonstandard past tense of *do*: "I done a lot of rodeoin'."
- with a standard past tense verb to indicate absoluteness or completion: "I done told you to zipper your lips."

This means it is common enough to be considered by a dictionary.